# duplicated file name - index.js - jest-haste-map

Tags: jestjs

I am getting this error with Jest - the file path is different which is making me wonder why this is complaining? I think i am being told that index.js is a duplicated name even though the mocks are on different paths - surely not? I am using mocks from both these in a test file - am i unable to use index files with jest?!

```
jest-haste-map: duplicate manual mock found: index
  The following files share their name; please delete one of them:
    * <rootDir>/dist/Actions/SendDistributions/__mocks__/index.js
    * <rootDir>/dist/Actions/SendQualifications/__mocks__/index.js

jest-haste-map: duplicate manual mock found: index
  The following files share their name; please delete one of them:
    * <rootDir>/dist/Actions/SendQualifications/__mocks__/index.js
    * <rootDir>/dist/Actions/SendLeads/__mocks__/index.js
```

Comment: I get this as well, but it seems to not be an error, just an unwarranted warning.  An annoying, unwarranted warning.

Comment: I agree! An unwarranted, annoying warning stopping me from using files with the same name, did you find a way around it? I didn't

Comment: No. I just live with the warning now. Getting used to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove the warning, you need to add the following to your jest config - `jest.config.js` or `package.json` etc.

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/.*/__mocks__"]
};
```

OR

**package.json**

```
"jest": {
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "<rootDir>/.*/__mocks__"
    ]
}
```

You can then continue to use mocks structured the way you have shown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - i think that would remove the error, but also prevent us using the mock in the test?

Comment: Not at all, you can continue to use the multiple `__mocks__/index.js` as normal. I have the exact same structure

Comment: I'm not understanding why this works, or why jest displays this warning in the first place.  But I've also worked with jest long enough to know that I don't care.  Jest does some weird unintuitive shit.